# Map Reduce does not emit large data sets

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query

I am facing issues in map reduce, whenever expected result data set is large it returns nothing, it works for small data sets like for 40 thousand documents. Following is the code and problem understanding. See, I used this code

```
search = "breaking bad f"

var emit = function(a,b){
    print(a);
}

map = function() {
    if(this.torrent_name.indexOf(search) > -1){
        emit(this._id, this.torrent_name);
    }

}

reduce = function(key,values){
    return values;
}

res = db.torrents.mapReduce(map,reduce,{out: { inline: 1 },query:{$text:{$search:search}},scope:{search:search},sort:{'seeders':-1}})

printjson(res);
```

Now the result to this job is:

```
{
"results" : [ ],
"timeMillis" : 503,
"counts" : {
    "input" : 39859,
    "emit" : 0,
    "reduce" : 0,
    "output" : 0
},
"ok" : 1
}
```

which makes sense because map reduce input is same as answer to below query

```
db.torrents.find({$text:{$search:"breaking bad f"}}).count()
output => 39859
```

Now the main issue come when I change the search string in map reduce job to "breaking bad s", the result shown is

```
{
"results" : [ ],
"timeMillis" : 329,
"counts" : {
    "input" : 0,
    "emit" : 0,
    "reduce" : 0,
    "output" : 0
},
"ok" : 1
}
```

which does not makes any because map reduce input is not equal to answer of below query

```
db.torrents.find({$text:{$search:"breaking bad s"}}).count()
output => 71484
```

From above results I come to conclusion that there is come memory issue but I don't know where and why. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your process here is flawed in a number of ways.

1. **Text search does not work like that**

   You are asking a [**`$text`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/query/text/) search query to match on partial words such as

   ```js
    "breaking bad s"
    "breaking bad f"
   ```

   In each case, the "s" and the "f" here are ignored as they are not a whole word. So the only terms looked for are "breaking" and "bad". And I do mean **"terms"** here a opposed to a *"phrase"* as in "breaking bad", as the syntax you are using does not do that, but only looks for the terms instead.

   They "might" be the phrase, but generally they will not be if the data being searched contains "breaking" or "bad" in any other combination.

   I don't know where you think those counts are coming from, but it certainly has nothing to do with the "non-word" that is appended there.
2. **The mapper is also wrong**

   Following on from above, since what you are actually matching here is "breaking" and "bad" as individual words, then it makes sense to only check that those "words" are present in the string. They will be of course, but the test is wrong and should be written like this:

   ```js
   map = function() {
       if ( /breaking|bad/.test(this.torrent_name) ) {
           emit(null,1);
       }
   };
   ```
3. **Reducer is wrong as well**

   More to the point, besides the "emits" failing earlier, the reducer would never be called at all. With `mapReduce` the idea is that all "common" `_id` values are sent to the reducer for "reduction" to a single value and then returned.

   The way you had this writen you are just trying to pass out `values` which is actually an array. If the reducer had fired, then this produces a "big" error, in that you can only return a "single" value. That is in fact why it is called a "reduce" stage, because you want to "reduce" the grouped data down to a single common point.

   So again we rewrite this to something logical:

   ```js
   var reduce = function(key,values) {
       return Array.sum(values);
   };
   ```

   Also noting here that what comes "out" of the emitted data from the mapper **must** be the same structure and type as what comes "out" of the reducer as well.

   This is because in order to handle "large data", mapReduce does not process the same grouped key "all at once", but rather in small "chunks". So data that comes "out" of a reducer, can end up going back "in" as one of the values to further reduce.

So finally if you run this:

```js
res = db.torrents.mapReduce(
    map,
    reduce,
    { 
        "out": { "inline": 1 },
        "query": { "$text":{ "$search" :search } }
    }
);
```

You may actually just get a sane response that tells you it did something.

But as you develop this further, take note of what is said above and fully read the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/command/mapReduce/), which also explains the points as descrived above.

Comment: well, thanks for your response but that was not helpful. Even if the change s to season and f to first, problem remain the same. 
Even if I change test from "indexOf" to regular expression "I" (or) operator, problem remains the same.

I already knew about those things what you've mentioned but, that is just a test script, and the things you mentioned has nothing to do with the problem I am facing. 

seems like you forgot to understand what is the main issue I am facing here.

Comment: @rawat0419 What main issue is that? As stated all of your processes are invalid and therefore you do not get a result. 1. Match correctly and understand what that is. 2. Main message is "emit correctly", emitting just `_id` and another field is certainly not what you want for a mapReduce. 3. Reduce correctly, where your reducer as written will simply error if ever called. You can tell me you "understand:" if you wish, but the listing you submitted with the question suggests otherwise. Hence the answer. Nothing to do with size. MapReduce handles much larger than what you have.

Comment: ok, so you're saying that the reason I am not getting results is my mapper and reducer are wrongly written. Point taken. but in that case it should not give results in both cases, it gives desired results for "breaking bad" but not for "breaking bad season"

Comment: @rawat0419 Your question does not ask that. It has two text searches with "incomplete" strings, and also does not use "phrases". If you want to know how to get "breaking bad season" or "breaking bad episode" in results then [ask another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). From my perspective, the **first** thing you needed to understand was all of the things you are doing incorrectly, and give you something that produces "a result", as opposed to the "nothing" you were currently getting. Look at the title of your question and what you really asked.

Comment: @rawat0419 Furthermore, beyond that I really cannot see what your question is. Turning *"does not work"* into *"does work"* is the only goal I see here. What I suspect you are really after, should not even require mapReduce at all. And therefore you are better off [asking another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Here you've learned something. I hope.

Comment: look, I know I'll get the results if I use phrase $text search. What you're not getting here is this is a TEST SCRIPT, this is a TEST SCRIPT, this is a TEST SCRIPT......  instead of understanding the issue here, you're stuck on  some worthless point of phrase text search and keep mentioning that. I know when and where I want a map reducer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87249/discussion-between-rawat0419-and-blakes-seven).